# Did multiselect with the javascript filter, but having some problems

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

### Best way for a multiselect directive in angularjs

I am developing a multiselect directive in angularjs (it must be in this technology since the project works on angularjs). The directive works with an array of inputdata and another of ouputdata, everything that is `"cheked: true"` in the inputdata is saved in the output data. I did this with the javascript filter, but I am having some problems with this. I wanted to know if there is a more optimal way to send each object with the mentioned property (cheked: true) to the ouptdata.

```
$scope.inputData = [
    { name: 'Dato 1', maker: 'Dato 1 Largo', group: 'Grupo 1', selected: true},
    { name: 'Dato 2', maker: 'Dato 2 Largo', group: 'Grupo 1', selected: false},
    { name: 'Dato 3', maker: 'Dato 3 Largo', group: 'Grupo 1', selected: true},
    { name: 'Dato 4', maker: 'Dato 4 Largo', group: 'Grupo 1', selected: false},
 ];
 $scope.ouputData = [
    { name: 'Dato 1', maker: 'Dato 1 Largo', group: 'Grupo 1', selected: true},
    { name: 'Dato 3', maker: 'Dato 3 Largo', group: 'Grupo 1', selected: true},
 ];
```

Comment: You mention "cheked: true", but your data has "selected: true". Also, "optimal" how? "Best" is not something Stack Overflow is really good at; we're good at questions that can be answered objectively.

Comment: Can you also explain what problem you are having?

There's O(N) solution only and inputData.filter(i -> i.selected) is already O(N).

Comment: The question needs to show the problematic code and needs a better description of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this ?

```
$scope.$watchCollection('inputData', function(newVal){
    if(newVal){
        $scope.outputData = newVal.filter(data => { return data.selected });
    }
});
```